# Getting the PropertyInfo of the Source property through Binding Markup Extension

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, markup-extensions, errortemplate

i am working on the error template through Attributes in the model's Property

so, whenever the binding happens,I want to read the custom attributes associated with the source property and add the appropriate validation rules to the Binding

but i am unable to find easy way to get the property info
considering fallowing scenarios in the binding 
1. possibility of relative Source's
2. extended binding's like Vm.SomeModel.Somotherobj.SomeProperty
3. indexers

is there any easy way out to get the PropertyInfo of the source from the Binding mark up extension?